# How can I hide weekends when using the ASP.NET Calendar control?

Tags: asp.net, calendar

Sometimes when displaying a calendar it is necessary to prevent the weekend days and the weekend names in the day header from showing, is there a way to do this using the [ASP.NET Calendar control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.aspx)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the  control is provided, there is no way to do this without overriding the control. One way of doing this is to is to override the [OnDayRender](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.ondayrender.aspx) and [Render](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.render.aspx) methods to remove the information from the output prior to sending it back to the client.

The following is a screen shot of what the control looks like when rendered:

[image: Example of weekday calendar]

The following is a basic control override that demonstrates removing the weekend day columns from the control.

```
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Author - Rob (http://stackoverflow.com/users/1185/rob)
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Notes
 * - This might not be the best way of doing things, so you should test it
 *   before using it in production code.
 * - This control was inspired by Mike Ellison's article on The Code Project
 *   found here: http://www.codeproject.com/aspnet/MellDataCalendar.asp
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

namespace DataControls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Example of a ASP.NET Calendar control that has been overriden to force
    /// the weekend columns to be hidden on demand.
    /// </summary>
    public class DataCalendar : Calendar
    {
        private bool _hideWeekend;
        private int _saturday;
        private int _sunday;

        /// <summary>Constructor</summary>
        public DataCalendar()
            : base()
        {
            // Default to showing the weekend
            this._hideWeekend = false;
            // Set the default values for Saturday and Sunday
            this.Saturday = 6;
            this.Sunday = 0;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Indicate if the weekend days should be shown or not, set to true
        /// if the weekend should be hidden, false otherwise. This field 
        /// defaults to false.
        /// </summary>
        public bool HideWeekend
        {
            get { return this._hideWeekend; }
            set { this._hideWeekend = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Override the default index for Saturdays.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>This option is provided for internationalization options.</remarks>
        public int Saturday 
        {
            get { return this._saturday; }
            set { this._saturday = value; }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Override the default index for Sundays.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>This option is provided for internationalization options.</remarks>
        public int Sunday 
        {
            get { return this._sunday; }
            set { this._sunday = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Render the day on the calendar with the information provided.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cell">The cell in the table.</param>
        /// <param name="day">The calendar day information</param>
        protected override void OnDayRender(TableCell cell, CalendarDay day)
        {
            // If this is a weekend day and they should be hidden, remove
            // them from the output
            if (day.IsWeekend && this._hideWeekend)
            {
                day = null;
                cell.Visible = false;
                cell.Text = string.Empty;
            }
            // Call the base render method too
            base.OnDayRender(cell, day);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Render the calendar to the HTML stream provided.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="html">The output control stream to write to.</param>
        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter html)
        {
            // Setup a new HtmlTextWriter that the base class will use to render
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
            HtmlTextWriter calendar = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            // Call the base Calendar's Render method allowing OnDayRender() 
            // to be executed.
            base.Render(calendar);
            // Check to see if we need to remove the weekends from the header,
            // if we do, then remove the fields and use the new verison for
            // the output. Otherwise, just use what was previously generated.
            if (this._hideWeekend && this.ShowDayHeader)
            {
                // Load the XHTML to a XML document for processing
                XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
                xml.Load(new StringReader(sw.ToString()));
                // The Calendar control renders as a table, so navigate to the
                // second TR which has the day headers.
                XmlElement root = xml.DocumentElement;
                XmlNode oldNode = root.SelectNodes("/table/tr")[1];
                XmlNode sundayNode = oldNode.ChildNodes[this.Sunday];
                XmlNode saturdayNode = oldNode.ChildNodes[this.Saturday];
                XmlNode newNode = oldNode;
                newNode.RemoveChild(sundayNode);
                newNode.RemoveChild(saturdayNode);
                root.ReplaceChild(oldNode, newNode);
                // Replace the buffer
                html.WriteLine(root.OuterXml);
            }
            else
            {
                html.WriteLine(sw.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a small comment that when I implemented this, the day headings ran from Tuesday to Saturday. The trick for me was to change the line:

    XmlNode sundayNode = oldNode.ChildNodes[0];  

to:  

    XmlNode sundayNode = oldNode.ChildNodes[5];  

Possibly due to me being in the UK?

Comment: @Brian - That would most likely be the case, I'm in the United States which uses Sunday as the first day of the week for the calendar. I didn't include anything in the way of localization logic in the code so that might be something for me to do at some point.

Comment: @Joel - Just implemented this and tested in IE, predictably it doesn't appear as one would hope. The weekday headers and day cells all render at 5/7th's of the width of the calendar. This is due to the two day columns that were removed. I have a fix for this (replace any 'width:14%' in the xml to 'width:20%') and would like to share my solution with others. What's the best way for me to go about this?

Comment: @Brian - I wrote the original modification as an example to build off of as opposed to a full production version. Your best best would likely to be to answer this question with your version or you could do a blog entry somewhere and post up a link.

Answer (score 0):

As far I know you can't, but you can experiment with WeekendDayStyle, for example by setting style with display:none. Alternatively, you can create custom control inherited from Calendar and override ether Render, OnDayRender or something else.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can handle the Day Render event and hide the cell or assign CSS properties to make it invisible or grayed out. Below is a simple example, I hope this helps.

```
protected void Calendar_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{

  e.Cell.Visible = False;
  // or
  // e.Cell.Attributes.Add("class", "Invisible");
  // or
  // e.Cell.Attributes.Add("style", "display: none");
}
```

Comment: This just hides the contents of the day field, you would still need to do additional work to be able to remove the day heading.

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK using a jQuery solution, it takes just a few lines of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('._title').parent().attr('colspan', '5'); // title row initially has a colspan of seven
        $('._dayheader:first, ._dayheader:last', $('#<%= Calendar1.ClientID %>')).hide(); // remove first and last cells from day header row
        $('._weekendday').hide(); // remove all the cells marked weekends
    });
</script>

<asp:Calendar runat="server" ID="Calendar1">
    <TitleStyle CssClass="_title" />
    <DayHeaderStyle CssClass="_dayheader" />
    <WeekendDayStyle CssClass="_weekendday" />
</asp:Calendar>
```

Here are some considerations with this approach:

- If JavaScript is disabled, the client will see weekends.
- In older, slower browsers, the calendar kind of jumps as the jQuery executes on load.
- This solution could probably be implemented in straight CSS with [:first-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp).
- If you add another calendar to the page, you will need to duplicate the middle line of JavaScript. This is necessary because we are using :first and :last.
- If you only have one calendar control on the page, you can simplify the middle line of JavaScript by removing the second argument of the jQuery selector: `$('#<%= Calendar1.ClientID %>')`

Answer (score 0):

As zacharydl have suggested I managed to hide the weekends using jQuery. I have made a small change to the original code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   HideWeekEnd();


    function HideWeekEnd ()
    {
        $('._title').parent().attr('colspan', '7');  
        $('._dayheader:nth-last-child(1) , ._dayheader:nth-last-child(2) ', $('#<%= Calendar1.ClientID %>')).hide(); // remove last two cells from day header row
        $('._weekendday').hide(); // remove all the cells marked weekends
    }

 Sys.Application.add_init(appl_init);

        function appl_init() {
            var pgRegMgr = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
            pgRegMgr.add_endRequest(HideWeekEnd);
        }

</script>
```

You will have to register the HideWeekEnd() in page endRequest to ensure its called during page post back.

Answer (score 0):

here is another way using CSS only to achieve that:

> ```
>  <style>
>    .hidden,
>    #Calendrier tr > th[abbr=Saturday],
>    #Calendrier tr > th[abbr=Sunday] { display:none; }
>    #Calendrier tr > th { text-align: center; }
>  </style>
>
>  <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" DayNameFormat="Full" runat="server" 
>                WeekendDayStyle-CssClass="hidden" ClientIDMode="Static"  >
>  </asp:Calendar>
> ```