# Hiding Day in calendar control (whole day column)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, calendar

I have calendar control in my page. It displayed all days of the week. Now, I want to delete Wednesday from the calender control. Only six days need to displayed.

I tried this:

```
if (e.Day.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
{
    e.Cell.Visible = false;

    // e.Cell.Text = string.Empty;
    // e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
    // e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
```

It is not working like expected. How do I delete a whole day from the calendar?

thanks for help in advance,
Ulas

Comment: You cant do this straight from ASP, it will have to be a CSS bodge

Comment: @ColinSteel - yes you can...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Day.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
    {
        e.Cell.Controls.Clear();
    }
}
```

It does leave the header (Wed) though, as mentioned in the comments below this can be fixed by adding the following to the CSS file:

```
.calendar tr > th:first-child + th + th + th + { display:none; }
```

Comment: like you said, it leaves the header. I want to make the header disappear to

Comment: @user3114347 Ok, had a quick search and found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554111/how-can-i-hide-weekends-when-using-the-asp-net-calendar-control) that relates to hiding a weekend in a calendar control. It's a bit more work but if you modify it it should do what you want.

Comment: i fixxed the header with this in my css   .calendar tr > th:first-child + th + th + th + 

{
    display:none;
}