# How do I remove the "week-end" of asp:calendar in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'd like to remove the saturday and the sunday (so the weekend) of my asp:calendar in ASP.
Do you have a property to add in the aspx page or we have to use the C# to do it ?

My code :

```
 <asp:Calendar ID="Calendrier" DayNameFormat="Full" runat="server">
                    <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="#fafad2" ForeColor="#ff0000" />
                    <DayHeaderStyle ForeColor="#0000ff" />
                    <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#21abe3" />
                </asp:Calendar>
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554111/how-can-i-hide-weekends-when-using-the-asp-net-calendar-control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could achieve this by using style sheet in your page, something like this;

css class

> ```
>   <style>
>     .hidden,
>     #Calendrier tr > th[abbr=Saturday],
>     #Calendrier tr > th[abbr=Sunday] { display:none; }
>     #Calendrier tr > th { text-align: center; }
>   </style>
> ```

and in your calendar you only need to make the client id static and set the css-class on the control itself, as below:

> ```
>    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendrier" DayNameFormat="Full" runat="server" 
>                    CssClass="calc-style" WeekendDayStyle-CssClass="hidden" 
>                    ClientIDMode="Static"  >
>          <DayHeaderStyle ForeColor="#0000ff" />
>          <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#21abe3" />
>    </asp:Calendar>
> ```

if you don't want to have a static id, then you need to take care of the control ID on your css class.

and here is the result:

[image]

Comment: It works but it remove only numbers of saturday and sunday. There is always the "saturday" and "sunday" columns which are displayed on the calendar.

Comment: make sure you add these two attributes in your calendar control `WeekendDayStyle-CssClass="hidden" ClientIDMode="Static"` and have the above css

Comment: I did a mistake (my calendar is French) so for me it's :  #Calendrier tr > th[abbr=samedi],
    #Calendrier tr > th[abbr=dimanche] { display:none; }